# Mail delivery failure occurred due to "Headers too large (32768 max)" using Outlook

Tags: exchange-server

I'm using Outlook 2016 and often encounter mail delivery failure due to "Headers too large (32768 max)" when I send email. Apparently, Office 365 adds a lot of mail header information when it transfers the email. Do you know if there is any way to decrease the header infromation from client side or server side ?